# this code i wrote to find the smallest number in an array using recursive functions

Tags: c

```
int smallest(int arr[],int i,int small,int n)
{
   if(i==n)
       return small;

    else  if(small>=arr[i])
   {
      smallest(arr,i+1,arr[i],n);
   }
}
```

so the compiler says that control reaches end of non-void function.Any suggestions?

Comment: you should return the result of the smallest in line 5!

Comment: Should be on the code review exchange

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it so that you can't fall out the end of the function without returning anything; e.g.

```
int smallest(int arr[],int i,int small,int n)
  {
  if (i == n)
    return small;
  else if(small >= arr[i])
    return smallest(arr, i+1, arr[i], n);
  else
    return smallest(arr, i+1, small, n);
  }
```

You also might want to provide an alternative-and-simpler call for user code to call which does the required initializations, in which case you might want to rename the above to `basic_smallest` and then create a new function

```
#include <limits.h>

int smallest(int arr[], int i)
  {
  return basic_smallest(arr, i, INT_MAX, 0);
  }
```

Also, keep in mind that a recursive implementation such as this puts you at risk of blowing up your stack for large arrays. A non-recursive implementation might be safer:

```
int smallest(int arr[], int i)
  {
  int n;
  int small;

  for(n = 0 ; n < i ; ++n)
    small = (small >= arr[n] ? arr[n] : small);

  return small;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two return cases in your logic flow, and you're making this harder than it needs to be regardless.

Regarding the two missing return statements, they are noted below:

```
int smallest(int arr[],int i,int small,int n)
{
    if(i==n)
        return small;

    else  if(small>=arr[i])
    {
        smallest(arr,i+1,arr[i],n); // here
    }

    // and here
}
```

Both of these become a bit more obvious when you remove the worthless `else` usage. It isn't needed. If the prior `if` is true, the function already exited.

```
int smallest(int arr[],int i,int small,int n)
{
    if(i==n)
        return small;

    if(small>=arr[i])
        smallest(arr,i+1,arr[i],n); // here

    // and here
}
```

Same problems, but now it should be visually more obvious the only place you actually return anything is when `i == n`. In neither case that follows (when `small >= arr[i]` is true OR false) is any return value provided.

The solution then, if keeping your existing interface, is to add the return AND the final case, thereby covering all logical paths to have a reachable `return`:

```
int smallest(int arr[],int i,int small,int n)
{
    if(i==n)
        return small;

    if(small>=arr[i])
        return smallest(arr,i+1,arr[i],n);

    return smallest(arr,i+1,small,n); // note small. it's important
}
```

---

**A Different Approach**

Recursive `smallest()` is doable using only a sequence address and a length. You need not tag along that `small` value, nor do you need the to tote around that index. Rather, you can simply use *pointer arithmetic* to move the base sequence address up until you exhaust your given elements, while adjusting the remaining sequence length that will eventually tell us we need to stop recursing. All of the relevant data is already kept for you in the recursion stack; you just need to know how to use it:

```
int smallest(const int arr[], size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2) // 1
        return *arr;

    int small = smallest(arr+1, len-1); // 2
    return (*arr < small ? *arr : small); // 3
}
```

Explanation of noted points below

1. Base bailout case. Just return whatever is at the start of the sequence if `len < 2` is true. There is a missing pedantic step I left out here. It is conceivable someone can pass a sequence of *zero* length, and if that is the case, it should be considered a runtime error. Keep that in mind if this is to be anything besides an exercise (which it looks like it is).
2. Get the smallest value of the elements that follow the base element of `*arr` using recursion. Note that `arr+1` is the first parameter. This means the recursed call will refer to the *next* element in the sequence as it's *base* element (`*arr`). Also note `len-1` is passed to note there are now one-fewer elements left in the sequence. We rely on that to trigger the base case from (1) above once the sequence is exhausted and we need to stop recursing.
3. Ternary expression that essentially says, "if the base element is less than the smallest of all the elements that followed, return the base element, otherwise return the smallest element that followed."

A sample run appears below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

#include <stdio.h>

int smallest(const int arr[], size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return *arr;

    int small = smallest(arr+1, len-1);
    return (*arr < small ? *arr : small);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 7,3,5,1,9,2,4,6,8 };
    printf("Smallest : %d\n", smallest(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr));
}
```

**Output**

```
Smallest : 1
```